# Созданным или созданными — как правильно (см. контекст)?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, грамматика

Из аннотации  к книге:
«„Стальной прыжок“ Пера Валё (1926–1975), известного российскому читателю преимущественно по детективам, созданным писателем в соавторстве с Май Шевалль (р. 1935), по форме — детектив, по сути — антиутопия».
Может быть, должно быть написано не «созданным», а «созданными»?
И совсем уж крамольная мысль: можно и так, и так?
Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

> Может быть, должно быть написано не «созданным», а «созданными»?

Нет, здесь ***детективам (каким?) - созданным***. 
А к какому слову вы собираетесь задать вопрос *(какими?) - созданными*.

Другое дело, что фраза тяжеловесна сверх всякой меры, отсюда и неуверенность в выборе формы. Но это уже проблема стилистики.

Можно было бы сказать "*известного*... ***детективами, созданными***..." — это чуть лучше воспринимается, но в целом фраза все одно тяжелая.

Answer (score 0):

В исходном варианте падеж *правильный*: известного по как**им** детективам? - по созданн**ым** в соавторстве. Вариант же «созданны**ми**» возможен в беспредложном случае: *известного* (чем?) *детективами,* (какими?) *созданными*...